# Adding tool-tip to an image rendered using Highcharts Renderer.image() api

Tags: image, highcharts, tooltip

I wanted to add a tool-tip to an image that is rendered using:
`image (String source, Number x, Number y, Number width, Number height) api`.

I couldn't figure out a way to do this, I am using `org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts` API's to
create high charts in my GWT app.

Answer (score 4):

Use `chart.renderer.text` and `chart.renderer.rect` to draw and position your own custom tooltip based on the position of the image.

This is a sample code snippet I used to display a tooltip for an image which is generated using `chart.renderer.image` -

```
marker = chart.renderer.image(src, x, y, imageSize, imageSize)
            .on('click', function() {`enter code here`
            })
            .attr({
              zIndex: 100
            })
            .on('mouseover', function() {
              //Call back for image mouse hover                     
              //Draw a text relative to Image X and Y                                                           
                  text = chart.renderer.text("Your tooltip Text",X, Y)
                        .add();

                        var box = text.getBBox();

                        //Now draw a box surrounding the tool tip text                     
            textBG = chart.renderer.rect(box.x, box.y,box.width, box.height, 5)
                .attr({
                    fill: '#FFFFEF',
                        stroke: 'gray',
                                    'stroke-width': 1,
                        zIndex: 4
                      })
                .add();
            })
               .on('mouseout', function() {

                         //Call back for mouse out on the image
                         //Destroy Both markers text and textBG on mouse out
                         //Make text and textBG as global functions for access accross functions 
                         text.destroy();
                         textBG.destroy();  

                         })
                 .add();
```

In this way you can create custom tooltip for images.

I used [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-on-chart/) link for syntax of adding tooltip text and its back ground to the chart.

Comment: Thank you. This was a really helpful pointer. I did use it to customize a component needed to render multiple chart markers (with customization color and tool-tips + event behavior and data).

Comment: Howto use with multiple rendered images? I'm try it but tooltips position alway show at last image position.